# Javascript elapsed time function observer

Tags: javascript, function, time

I would like to know **IF** and **HOW** it is possible to write a `function` which observes an other function.
More precisely, the `obsever` keeps track of the the `observed` function **execution time**, and in case the latter exceeds a given time value, the `observer` function **stop** it.

So, briefly:

```
function observed() { // ... }

/**
 * Run a function and stop if this exceeds a given time.
 *
 * @param {Function} observedFunc The function to run and observe.
 * @param {Number} maxTime The maximum elapsed time allowed.
 */
function observer(observedFunc, maxTime) {
   /*
    * if (observedFunc exceed the time) 
    *     stop observedFunc;
    *     return;
    * else
    *     return; (when the observed function return)
    */
}
```

Is it possible to afford this, without changing the `observed` function?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to stop the execution of the function externally - you would have to build the timeout into your observed() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with  [Web Workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) in browsers that support it.  If you ran `observed` from withing a Web Worker, then the main script could call [terminate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#terminate-a-worker) on the worker.

Normally (at least historically) Javascript is [single threaded](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#javascript-is-single-threaded), and so while `observed` is running, `observer` has no way of stopping it.